# Python Pandas error: pandas can only use .str accessor with string values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas script where I get an excel sheet and put it on a pandas dataframe, then I am looking in this dataframe for a specific word, then I create a mask of 1 and 0 of the df, where I find the word.

I don't have a specific format for the excel sheet so I get all the info as is, and I look for the word and create a mask with this line which produce the error:

```
mask = np.column_stack([df[col].str.find(word) for col in df.columns.tolist()]).astype(int)
```

this line **sometimes** produce this error:

> pandas can only use .str accessor with string values, which use
>   np.object_ dtype in pandas

any idea why and how to make it work?

thank you

Comment: Try `df.select_dtypes([np.object]).columns.tolist()` instead of `df.columns.tolist()` in your list comprehension. Right now, you are selecting all the `dtypes` of columns which could very well be mixed. You need to confine this to only the string ones for `str.find()` function to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `applymap` with a `lambda` function to convert the dataframe to a mask.
If `df` is your input dataframe, you can do the following to convert all fields to `1` if the string `word` is in it or `0` otherwise.

```
mask = df.applymap(lambda x: 1 if word in str(x) else 0)
```